# Stacked cards w bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a set of cards that I'm trying to stack. The images aren't fitting the cards properly. They only fit the card when I hover over it. Also, the function I have for them to scroll isn't working when I click them. I have provided a screenshot and my code below. Thanks!:

Screenshot of the issue:

[image: stacked card]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SP Card stack</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!--Studio List-->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card1-stack">
          <!---Button for scroll-->
          <a class="buttons prev" href="#"><</a>
          <!---Button for scroll-->
          <ul class="card-list">

            <!--Studio Front Page-->
            <li class="card1 text-white card-has-bg click-col" style="background-image:url('https://westlakepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/SnoopDoggStudio.jpg');">
              <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="mr-3 rounded-circle"
                      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxUXsEFPioqCqDqgp7MeLNpM7iZYL6mt97ElI3LwCnuFoarwmSWbJquoEwbi1AJSRzXBs&usqp=CAU"
                      alt="Generic placeholder image" style="max-width:50px">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h6 class="card-meta mb-2"><strong>CC Studios</strong></h6>
                      <small class="stuLocation">Bethesda, MD</small>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--Heart Button--->
                  <div class="btns1">
                    <Button style="font-size: 35px" onclick="Toggle1()" id="btnh1" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></Button>
                  </div>
                  <!---Heart Button--->
                  <!---Star Rating--->
                  <div class="rating-box">
                    <div class="star-source">
                      <svg>
                            <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="5.41294643%" x2="87.5527344%" y2="65.4921875%" id="grad">
                                <stop stop-color="#bf209f" offset="0%"></stop>
                                <stop stop-color="#d62a9d" offset="60%"></stop>
                                <stop stop-color="#ED009E" offset="100%"></stop>
                            </linearGradient>
                        <symbol id="star" viewBox="153 89 106 108">   
                          <polygon id="star-shape" stroke="url(#grad)" stroke-width="5" fill="currentColor" points="206 162.5 176.610737 185.45085 189.356511 150.407797 158.447174 129.54915 195.713758 130.842203 206 95 216.286242 130.842203 253.552826 129.54915 222.643489 150.407797 235.389263 185.45085"></polygon>
                        </symbol>
                    </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="star-container">
                      <input type="radio" name="star" id="five">
                      <label for="five">
                        <svg class="star">
                          <use xlink:href="#star"/>
                        </svg>
                      </label>
                      <input type="radio" name="star" id="four">
                      <label for="four">
                        <svg class="star">
                          <use xlink:href="#star"/>
                        </svg>
                      </label>
                      <input type="radio" name="star" id="three">
                      <label for="three">
                        <svg class="star">
                          <use xlink:href="#star"/>
                        </svg>
                      </label>
                      <input type="radio" name="star" id="two">
                      <label for="two">
                        <svg class="star">
                          <use xlink:href="#star" />
                        </svg>
                      </label>
                      <input type="radio" name="star" id="one">
                      <label for="one">
                      <svg class="star">
                        <use xlink:href="#star" />
                      </svg>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!---Star Rating--->
                
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <!--Studio Front Page-->

            <!--Studio Room 1-->
            <li class="card1 text-white card-has-bg click-col" style="background-image:url('https://westlakepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/SnoopDoggStudio.jpg');">
              <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="card-body">
              </div>
            </li>
            <!--Studio Room 1-->


          </ul>
          <a class="buttons next" href="#">></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Studio One-->








    


    <!--Studio List-->


    <script src="cardstack.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*---Card One---*/

  /*---Card Body---*/
  .card1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 45px;
    right: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 420px;
    height: 330px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }

  .stuLocation{
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
  }
  .card1.card-has-bg {
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
    background-size: 120%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
  }


  .card1.card-has-bg:hover {
    transform: scale(0.98);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background-size: 130%;
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  }

  .card1.card-has-bg:hover .card-img-overlay {
    transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #d2d2d25c 100%);
  }

  .card1 .card-meta {
    color: #9370DB;
  }

  .card1 .card-body {
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  }

  .card1:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  }

  .card1:hover .card-body {
    margin-top: 30px;
    transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  }

  .card1 .card-img-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.425);
  }

  

  /*---Card Body---*/

  /*---Heart Button---*/
  .btns1{
    position: relative;
    top: -70px;
    left: 300px;
  }
  /*---Heart Button---*/

  /*---Star Rating---*/
  .rating-box {
  position: relative;
  top: -75px;
  left: -60px;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  width: 105px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #e5e5e55a;
  border: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  svg {
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  }


  /* hide radio buttons */
  input[name="star"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -2px;
  }

  /* hide source svg */
  .star-source {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  }


  /* set initial color to transparent so fill is empty*/
  .star {
  color: #7a7a7a;

  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }


  /* set direction to row-reverse so 5th star is at the end and ~ can be used to fill all sibling stars that precede last starred element*/
  .star-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  }

  label:hover ~ label .star,
  svg.star:hover,
  input[name="star"]:focus ~ label .star,
  input[name="star"]:checked ~ label .star {
  color: #fbff28;
  }

  input[name="star"]:checked + label .star {
  animation: starred 0.5s;
  }

  input[name="star"]:checked + label {
  animation: scaleup 1s;
  }

  @keyframes scaleup {
  from {
      transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  to {
      transform: scale(1);
  }
  }

  @keyframes starred {
  from {
      color: #d6ca2a;
  }
  to {
      color: #d6ca2a;
  }
    }
  /*---Star Rating---*/

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .card {
      min-height: 350px;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 420px) {
    .card {
      min-height: 300px;
    }
  }




  /*---Card stack---*/
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 50px 80px;
  }
  .container .card1-stack {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 20px auto;
  }
  .container .card1-stack .buttons {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    left: 0;
    top: 55%;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    z-index: 100;
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
  }
  .container .card1-stack .buttons:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
  }
  .container .card1-stack .prev {
    left: 15px;
    right: auto;
  }
  .container .card1-stack .next {
    left: auto;
    right: 15px;
  }
  .container .card1-stack .carousel .buttons:hover {
    color: #C01313;
    background: #fff;
  }
  .container .card1-stack .card-list {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .container .card1-stack .card-list__image {
    height: 200px;
  }
  .container .card1-stack .card-list__text {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  .container .card1-stack .card-list li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    height: 300px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .container .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(1) {
    top: 24px;
    width: 60%;
    /* animation: scaleCard 100ms; */
  }
  .container .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(2) {
    top: 36px;
    width: 70%;
  }
  .container .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(3) {
    top: 48px;
    width: 80%;
  }
  .container .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(4) {
    top: 60px;
    width: 90%;
  }
  .container .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(5) {
    top: 72px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .container .card1-stack:hover > .buttons.prev {
    display: block;
    animation: bounceInLeft 200ms;
  }
  .container .card1-stack:hover > .buttons.next {
    display: block;
    animation: bounceInRight 200ms;
  }
  .transformThis {
    animation: scaleDown 500ms;
  }
  .transformPrev {
    animation: scaleUp 100ms;
    display: none;
  }
  @keyframes scaleUp {
    0% {
      transform: scale(1.2) translateY(50px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    20% {
      transform: scale(1.15) translateY(40px);
      opacity: 0.1;
    }
    40% {
      transform: scale(1.1) translateY(30px);
      opacity: 0.2;
    }
    60% {
      transform: scale(1.05) translateY(20px);
      opacity: 0.4;
    }
    80% {
      transform: scale(1.01) translateY(10px);
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  @keyframes scaleDown {
    0% {
      transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    20% {
      transform: scale(1.01) translateY(20px);
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
    40% {
      transform: scale(1.05) translateY(40px);
      opacity: 0.4;
    }
    60% {
      transform: scale(1.1) translateY(60px);
      opacity: 0.2;
    }
    80% {
      transform: scale(1.15) translateY(80px);
      opacity: 0.1;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1.2) translateY(100px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  @keyframes scaleCard {
    0% {
      top: 5px;
    }
    100% {
      top: 24px;
    }
  }
  @keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(40px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }
  @keyframes bounceInRight {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(-40px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }

  /*---Card stack---*/

/*---Card One---*/
```

JS:

```
var $card = $('.card1');
var lastCard = $(".card-list .card").length - 1;

$('.next').click(function(){ 
    var prependList = function() {
        if( $('.card1').hasClass('activeNow') ) {
            var $slicedCard = $('.card1').slice(lastCard).removeClass('transformThis activeNow');
            $('ul').prepend($slicedCard);
        }
    }
    $('li').last().removeClass('transformPrev').addClass('transformThis').prev().addClass('activeNow');
    setTimeout(function(){prependList(); }, 150);
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var appendToList = function() {
        if( $('.card1').hasClass('activeNow') ) {
            var $slicedCard = $('.card1').slice(0, 1).addClass('transformPrev');
            $('.card-list').append($slicedCard);
        }}
    
            $('li').removeClass('transformPrev').last().addClass('activeNow').prevAll().removeClass('activeNow');
    setTimeout(function(){appendToList();}, 150);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `.card1.card-has-bg`'s background-size to `130%` that can solve image fitting problem

```
 .card1.card-has-bg {
   transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
   background-size: 130%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
 }
```

I test the function you provide

When I click button of .prev or .next, it works

I saw you use jQuery but you did not source cdn of jQuery in your HTML

So, you should source cdn of jQuery in HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```